# HTML pop-up from button click

Tags: html

I have a website that I want to click a button and have a pop-up to confirm if the user wants to proceed or not. I've seen several questions that use a link and have some kind of pop-up, but none that have a button with a pop-up. I've tried a few things, but they don't work the way that I want them to. Currently I have:

```
<p>Copy website files from MAFINFWWWPV02 to MAFINFWWWPV01</p>
<form action='Admin.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' onclick="myFunction()">
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='CopyFiles'/>
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Copy Files'/></p>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

and then this:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var x;
    if (confirm("Copy all files?") == true)
    {
        x = "You pressed OK!";/*Want this to run the .bat*/
    }
    else
    {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";/*Want this to not run the .bat*/
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

This will run a .bat file. It does this regardless of whether I have clicked the 'Ok' or 'Cancel' button. I want to click 'Ok' and have the .bat run or click the 'Cancel' and not have it run. I don't know how to stop it from running.

I have a `switch($_REQUEST['action'])` in my code that looks for the 'action' from the buttons on the page. For this `case` it does this:

```
case 'CopyFiles':
$script = chr(92) . chr(92) . 'MAFINFWWWPV02\D$\WebContent\engsys.corp.ftr.com\BatchFiles\CopyFiles.bat';
system('cmd /c ' . $script); echo " <br>";
break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event here is on the *form*:

```
<form action='Admin.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' onclick="myFunction()">
```

So it's going to fire that event when you click *anything* in the form.  I suspect you want it in the *onsubmit* event instead?:

```
<form action='Admin.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

Additionally, you have to actually cancel the form post following the `confirm()` response.  First, add a `return` to the function call:

```
<form action='Admin.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' onsubmit="return myFunction()">
```

Then you'll also want to use a combination of "preventing default" and "returning false".  Something like this:

```
function myFunction(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); // here
    var x;
    var response = confirm("Copy all files?");
    if (response == true)
    {
        x = "You pressed OK!";
    }
    else
    {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    return response; // and here
}
```

So if the `confirm()` response is `true`, the function returns `true` and the form continues to submit.  Else, the function returns `false` and the form doesn't submit.

Note that when the form submits, that update to the `demo` element will be gone because the page will refresh.

Comment: Perfect, that did exactly what I wanted. I didn't really care about the update to the demo element that was just so I could see if the click did something so I actually got rid of the whole `if` statement and just made it `var x = confirm("Copy all files?"); return x;`